# Can not Create multiple apps using fabric

Tags: android, google-fabric

I have two apps. Their application ids are same but the package names are not. However, fabric does not create a two separate apps but one (merged). Is there a way to separate the two apps?

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Firstly delete that app by logging into fabric.io.
2. In Android Studio, install the fabric plugin.
3. Then open one project at a time in android studio and use Fabric plugin to integrate fabric.
4. Integrate Fabric one by one.

For more reference using this link : https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-crashlytics-for-android-by-fabric-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about two different applications then the applications with same application ids cannot go to GooglePlay together. I am not understanding clearly if you have uploaded the two applications to GooglePlay already?

In the same way the Fabric also needs the separate application id to identify a unique application. Hence applications with same ids will merge them under same application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

application ID's must be unique for fabric integration.you can not add multiple apps with same application id --its a wrong

You can add but don't open multiple projects in android studio, open at a time one project then it will work fine no issue.

Answer (score -1):

application ID's must be unique for fabric integration.you can not add multiple apps with same application id

Comment: so,if I must be change application id?   but I need again upload google store when I change application id 。